# How to convert the following string to python date?

Tags: python, datetime, type-conversion

How can I convert: `u'2012-11-07T13:25:10.703Z'` to Python datetime?

**EDIT**

I intend to use something like this:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime('2011-03-07','%Y-%m-%d')
datetime.datetime(2011, 3, 7, 0, 0)
```

but how can I change the second argument to accommodate my date format?

Comment: In what way is this not working?

Comment: @hughdbrown He wants to parse hours, minutes, seconds, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`datetime.datetime.strptime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html?highlight=strptime#datetime.datetime.strptime):

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(u'2012-11-07T13:25:10.703Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
```

Result:

```
datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 7, 13, 25, 10, 703000)
```

See the description of [the `strptime` behaviour](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html?highlight=strptime#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Answer (score 0):

Use strptime from the datetime module

```
import datetime
datetime.strptime(u'2012-11-07T13:25:10.703Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
>>> datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 7, 13, 25, 10, 703000)
```

Comment: This won't work since `datetime.strptime` doesn't exits. It is `datetime.datetime.strptime`.