# MySql to Python Date

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, datetime, pyqt4

I try to convert MySQl datetime to same in Python.On debug there is

ValueError: time data '2001-06-04T11:30:35' doesn't match format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S .
In MySQL there is no 'T' in data.I tried format with 'T' and without.

I saw this article [How to convert the following string to python date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13271465/how-to-convert-the-following-string-to-python-date) .

This is code:

```
query = QSqlQuery ()
query.exec_("SELECT birthday FROM vista.user ")    
def countAge(birthday):
    birthday = datetime.strptime(str(birthday), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
    today = date.today()
    age = today.year - birthday.year
    if today.month < birthday.month:
        age -= 1
    elif today.month == birthday.month and today.day < birthday.day:
        age -= 1
    if age >= 0 :   
        return age
ages = []
index = 0
while (query.next()):
    print(query.value(index).toString())
    ages.append(countAge(query.value(index).toString()))
    index = index + 1
```

What is a problem?

Comment: So what is the output of: `print(query.value(index).toString())`?

Comment: 2001-06-04T11:30:35

Comment: @ekhumoro , It was for test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an example date-string is `2001-06-04T11:30:35`, then you need:

```
    birthday = datetime.strptime(str(birthday), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
```